# Alternatives to hardcoding parameters in alert metrics in grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus, grafana-alerts

I am trying to implement alerting using grafana and prometheus.

As Grafana does not allow template variables in metrics to be used in alerting, I am currently forced to hardcode the IP's if I want to collect the memory metrics.

But that's not a solution that can long last, as the nodes in my setup can terminate and get recreated as auto-scaling is enabled.

Is there any better alternative than hardcoding each instance IP in the metric and still enable alerting on memory usage of each node?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's why we've given up on using alerts in Grafana and decided to use [Alertmanager](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/overview/). For that you'll need to create alert rules and add them to PrometheusRule resource on the cluster and configure alertmanager itself.

Answer (score 0):

if you can figure out how to add your required info into labels, you can reference labels in your alert message using the template like so:

`{{$labels.instance}}`

Anything that's reported in the instance as a label should be available, however, it's only available if the alert ends in a math expression. It isn't available for alerts that use a classic expression.